# Chef : issue while running rspec

Tags: rspec, chef-infra

I wrote a small rspec test case while will call a recipe which inturn uses encrypted data bags.

while running " chef exec rspec", I get an error -

## received :[] with unexpected arguments

expected: ("private_props")
       got: ("private_password")
 Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.

I have the data bag in my cookbook at right place and kitchen converge runs fine.
Can someone help me whats wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you have a stub set up for the key `"private_props"` but the key `"private_password"` is being accessed and the stub doesn't know how to respond. Either add it to the stub or stop whatever is accessing that key.